# Python DNS Change Server

Tags: python, dns

What is the easiest way of changing the server that is queryed againest when using dnspython
Ive been using the following,

```
dns.resolver.query(hostname,type)
```

However from the documentation it appears you can only change the file it looks at for its resolver servers.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Resolver`](http://www.dnspython.org/) can load configuration either from the Windows registry or from `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you want to configure dns server manually, don't read system configuration (create it with `configure=False`) and configure it yourself.

`Resolver` has the [`nameservers`](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.10.0/html/dns.resolver.Resolver-class.html#nameservers) property which is a list of DNS servers IPs (as strings).

Comment: Links are broken